# Rails Bootstrap 4 with Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, turbolinks

I have a fully functional rails app with the [bootstrap-rubygem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) (v4.3) installed.

In my app I have a partial that gets re-rendered when a `remote: true` link is clicked. When this link is clicked I have a controller that responds to JS and then in my `.js.erb` view I replace the html of a specific div.

Now in this partial view, I make use of tooltips & dropdown. The problem is, the tooltips only work after a hard refresh. As soon as I click to reload the partial remotely, the tooltips stop working. The exact opposite is true for the dropdowns. They don't work until I click on the remote link.

Have I missed anything in setting up this gem or am I perhaps making a mistake in the way I'm implementing bootstrap with JQuery & Turbolinks?

**Main JS file: application.js**

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

**Main Layout File: application.haml**

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
    %title Dummy App
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = csp_meta_tag
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
  %body
    #sample-wrapper= render "sample/index"
    = yield
```

**JS view to render content in div: sample/index.js.erb**

```
$("#sample-wrapper").html("<%= j (render 'sample/index' ) %>");
```

**HAML view to with tooltip & dropdowns sample/index.haml**

```
.card
  %h1{data: {toggle: "tooltip", placement: "bottom", title: @sample.title}}= @sample.title
  .dropdown.card-options
    %button#dropdownMenu1.btn.btn-ghost.dropdown-toggle.no-caret{"aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-haspopup" => "true", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", :type => "button"}
      = fa_icon "ellipsis-h"
    .dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-right{"aria-labelledby" => "dropdownMenu1"}
      = link_to "Edit", edit_sample_path(@sample.token), class: "dropdown-item", remote: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reinitialize tooltip

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

after rerender partial, you can add it after render in your js.erb file

to solve peoblem with dropdown you have to initialize them on turbolinks:load like the tooltip is