# Rails turbolink js issue one click dropdown js not load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Rails js load issue Turbolinks gem.
Navbar Dropdown one click not open after page refresh or second click to open dropdown how to solve this isssue. and also kuse turbolinks gem and boostrap gem.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <% if current_user.present? %>
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
     <% Tabs::NAVBAR.each do|tab_key, tab|%>
       <% if tab[:type].eql?('dropdown_tab') %>
         <li class="nav-item dropdown <%= active_navbar(tab_key) %>">
           <% if current_user.projects.present? %>
              <%= link_to tab[:title], fetch_route(tab_key), class: 'nav-link dropdown-toggle', id: 'myTab', data: { toggle: "dropdown" }%>
          <%else%>
          <%end%>
         <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <% dropdown_options(tab_key).each do|option| %>
            <%= link_to option[:title], option[:path], class:'dropdown-item' %>
          <% end %>
          </div>
         </li>
       <% else %>
        <li class="nav-item <%= active_navbar(tab_key) %>">
         <%= link_to tab[:title], fetch_route(tab_key), class: 'nav-link'%>
        </li>
     <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Profile <b class="caret"></b></a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
       <li><%= link_to " Profile", edit_user_registration_path, class: "dropdown-item" %></li>
       <li><%= link_to " Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "dropdown-item" %></li>
   </div>  
  </div>
<%end%>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Show your code. The benefit of turbolinks is that it is *not a full page reload*, it just replaces the HTML content of the *existing page* (kinda like if you did `document.body.innerHTML = newPage` plus some stuff for head). A lot of JS at global scope or on load event handlers will not run.

Comment: Thanks for response, Already add code my nav bar project drop-down take double click to show . if you want show other code i will add code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to reinitialize the elements that requires bootstrap js when the event `turbolinks:load` is fired, check this question [Rails Bootstrap 4 with Turbolinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364890/rails-bootstrap-4-with-turbolinks)

It's about the tooltip js, but the same applies for any element that requires js initialization.

Something like:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need `Dropdown.parseDocument(element)` or `Bulma(element).dropdown()` in `turbolinks:load` event when used `@vizuaalog/bulmajs`.

```js
// global `bulmaOptions` object should be defined before BulmaJS has loaded
// disable autoParse to prevent repeated `turbolinks:load` event
window.bulmaOptions = {
  autoParseDocument: false 
}
// import Dropdown from '@vizuaalog/bulmajs/src/plugins/dropdown';
import Bulma from "@vizuaalog/bulmajs";

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  Bulma.parseDocument();
  // Dropdown.parseDocument(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]);

  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown')).forEach(element => {
    Bulma(element).dropdown();
  });
});
```

**Note: `bulmaOptions.autoParseDocument = false`**